# Is flop per second a measure of the speed of a processor, or a measure of the speed of an algorithm?

Tags: optimization, floating-point, code-analysis

1) I can see very clearly that: the number of floating point operations a computer can do in one second is a good way of quantifying its performance. That's correct, right?

2) My teacher keeps asking me to calculate the flop rate for algorithms I program. I do this by calculating how many flops the algorithm does and timing how long it takes to run. In this situation the flop rate always falls way short of the flop rate I expect from the computer I'm using. So for algorithms, is a flop rate more an assessment of how long the 'other stuff' takes (i.e. overheads, stuff that doesn't involve flopping). That is, when the flop count is low, most of the programs time is spent calling functions etc. and not performing flop, correct?

I know this is a very broad question but I was hoping for some ideas from those in industry or academia about what they intuitively feel the flop rate of an algorithm actually is.

Comment: The best answer to the title question might well be “yes."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properly, “flops” is a measure of processor or system performance. Many people misuse it as a measure of implementation or algorithm speed.

Suppose you had a computation to perform that is fixed in the number of operations it takes. For example, you want to multiply a matrix with dimensions a•b with a matrix with dimensions b•c. If you perform this multiplication in the usual way, then, in each combination of one of a rows and one of c columns, you perform b multiplications and b-1 additions. So the entire matrix multiplication takes a•c•(2b-1) floating-point operations. If it finishes in one second, some people say it is providing a•c•(2b-1) flops.

If you have two programs that both do the multiplication the same way, you can compare them using this figure. The one of them that has more “flops” is better. Even though they use the same algorithm, one of them might have a better implementation, perhaps because it organizes the work more efficiently for memory cache.

This breaks when somebody figures out a new algorithm that gets the same job done with fewer operations. Then some people compare programs (or routines) using the nominal number of operations of the original method, even though the program actually performs fewer operations.

To some extent, this makes sense. If you have two programs that do the same job, and one of them has a higher number of “flops” calculated this way, then it is the program that gives you the answer more quickly.

However, it does not make sense to the extent that it introduces inaccuracy. We are often not interested in a single problem size but in various sizes, and the “flops” of a program will not scale linearly with the nominal number of operations once a new algorithm is used.

By analogy, suppose it is 80 kilometers from town A to town B over the mountain road that everybody uses. If it takes your car an hour to make the trip, your car is traveling 80 kilometers an hour. While out exploring one day, you discover a pass through the mountains that reduces the trip to 70 kilometers. Now you can make the trip in 52.5 minutes. The same calculation that some people do with “flops” would say your car is going 91.4 kilometers per hour, since it makes the 80-kilometer trip in 52.5 minutes.

That is obviously wrong. However, it is useful for deciding which route to take.

Answer (score 0):

FLOPS means the amount of Floating Point Operations Per Second, executed by a processor. That can be a purely theoretical figure derived from some hardware/architecture specification or an empirical result from running some algorithm that is tuned to give high numbers.

The main issue in FLOPS calculation comes from a system, where there are multiple and parallel execution blocks. AFAIK, only in that context it starts to get really tough to split a practical algorithm (e.g. FFT, or RGB->YUV conversion) to the most useful set of instructions, that use all the calculation units in a CPU. (e.g. without automatic vectorization a x64 system often calculates Floating point operations only in the Xmm0[0] register, wasting 50-75% of the full potential.)

This partly answers the question 2. Besides of the obvious stall introduced by cache/memory to register bandwidth, the next crucial obstacle in the way to maximum FLOPS figures is that the data is in the wrong register. That's something that is often completely ignored in complexity analysis that just like FLOPS calculations only count basic arithmetic operations. In case of parallel programming, it often happens, that there are not only one, but 4, 8 or 16 values in wrong registers without any means of easily permuting them all at once. Add that to the overhead, "warm up" and "cool down" stages in an algorithm that tries to occupy all the calculating units with meaningful data and there you have major reasons for getting 100 MFlops out of a 1GFLOPS system.